# How to get CSV files values that are in seperate rows to combobox tkinter | Python

Tags: python, tkinter

I want to see the options in combobox separately in different line. I have tried the following, but doing this gives all the options in single line and not separately. Once they are in separate lines I would want to print the selected one.

```
    import csv
    from tkinter import *
    from tkinter import ttk
    import tkinter as tk
    app = tk.Tk()

    with open('apple.csv') as csv_file:
    csv_reader = csv.reader(csv_file)
    data = list(csv_reader)     

    e1 = ttk.Combobox(app,values=[data])
    e1.grid(row=0, column=1)

    message_text = StringVar()
    message_text = Label(app, text='Fruit name', pady=5)
    message_text.grid(row=0,column=0)

    #size
    app.title('Fruits')
    app.geometry("700x500")

    app.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Line 11: `values=[data]` You are converting data (list) into another list, so if data is `['apple', 'orange']` you are ending up with `[['apple','orange']]`

To fix simply remove the brackets `e1 = ttk.Combobox(app,values=data)`